# How to create api sub-resource in django rest framework

Tags: java, django, rest, django-rest-framework

So coming from a java stack where one can create sub-resource using any of the java-ee stack (jax-rs, jersey, restlet, rest-easy).

A java sample code snippet might look something like this.

```
@Path('library')
public class Library{
   // some get post resource endpoint
   @Path('books')
   BookResource bookSubResource() {}

}
```

So if this were to be achieved in django rest framework.
What is the best way or pattern to go about this, given we have a resource
APIView called `LibraryAPIView` and `BookAPIView`

Thanks

Comment: It would be more useful if you provide an API (path and body) you want to build instead of Java code.

Comment: Still don't get you, the path are libary and books.

Comment: For path I mean URL. Do you need `library/1/books` URL? Or do you need just `library/` and books should be a nested key?